# adding 2nd foreign keys in one table - MySql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I want to add 2nd foreign key on my existing table 'tbl_subcaste', its already having one '**fk caste caste_id**' ass shown below:
[image]

now i want to add another '**fk religion religion_id**' on this table as shown below :
[image]

but MySql giving me this error after doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_subcaste` 
ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk religion religion_id` 
FOREIGN KEY (`religion_id`) REFERE `sanskrut`.`tbl_religion`(`religion_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Error: #1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-534_f7'**

I can't understand, why this is not alloeing me to add another kf ?

Comment: Check the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` in both tables.  They should probably be `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci`.  (But other pairs are possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems foreign key name already exist, so just change it and try as per below-

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_subcaste` 
ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk religion religion_id100` 
FOREIGN KEY (`religion_id`) REFERE `sanskrut`.`tbl_religion`(`religion_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Even you should follow a standard to avoid this issue as you can keep name as "fk_tablename_columnname".

Further you can use below query to get all key names and other useful information.

```
SELECT constraint_Schema AS mydb, table_name AS child_table,constraint_name AS foreign_key_name, referenced_table_name AS master_table 
FROM information_Schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE constraint_Schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
```

Comment: thanks it seems working, but how can i check all fk in my table is having, do you know ?

Comment: as you suggested fk_tablename_columnname but my table names are also having underscore  ( _ ) so if i put 'fk_tbl_religion_religion_id ' , then i think its looking confusing  ? what's your opinion ?

Comment: name does not matter, so you can keep any thing by following some standard you can avoid duplicate issue you can keep as it is or can avoid _ between table name and column name...reason of this standard that you can make only single foreign key on any table's any column so if you follow it fk_tblname_colname then always it will be unique....

Comment: just to correct wording that only single foreign key it should be normally single foreign key on any field in rare case can multiple then we can add suffix in foreign key name....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the syntax "REFERENCES". Try the below query

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_subcaste  
ADD CONSTRAINT `f.k` FOREIGN KEY (`religion_id`) REFERENCES sanskrut.tbl_religion(`religion_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: the problem was, foreign key name already exist. just see above answer.

Comment: I would suggest you go through [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog), because it would pop an error when you use an existing foreign-key name. It is more user-friendly compared to the one you are using.